# Does the "Lightning Process" successfully treat Chronic Fatigue Syndrome?

Tags: alternative-medicine, healthcare

My partner suffers from [Myalgic Encephalopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronic_fatigue_syndrome) (ME) otherwise known as Chronic Fatigue Sydrome. It is a condition that remains not particularly well understood, even to the point where there doesn't seem to be any diagnosable root cause - just a collection of symptoms.

One of the treatments we've had suggested is called the [Lightning Process](http://lightningprocess.com/).

> Reducing allostatic load is considered to vital for improving chronic health conditions (Logan & Barksdale, 2008);  the Lightning Process does this by teaching you how to spot when the [Physical Emergency Response] is happening and how you can calm this response down, allowing your body to re-balance itself.

The [Action for ME](http://www.actionforme.org.uk/get-informed/publications/interaction-magazine/read-selected-ia-articles/treatments/alternative-approaches/lightning-process-your-experiences) charity describe the Lightning Process as

> a training program (not a therapy) that combines concepts from Neuro Linguistic Programming (NLP), hypnotherapy and life coaching.

It seems to combine all the things that make me skeptical - it works for some, not for others, and therefore makes me suspicious that it might be a program based on the placebo effect.

Are there any studies as to the outcomes of this process that indicates its efficacy?